# How to share a object between two Mybatis interceptors?

Tags: mybatis

I want to set value to a custom object in the first interceptor

```
@Intercepts(
    {
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "update", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class}),
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "query", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class, RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class}),
        @Signature(type = Executor.class, method = "query", args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class, RowBounds.class, ResultHandler.class, CacheKey.class, BoundSql.class}),
    }
)
public class FirstInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Setter
    private List<InnerInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      ...
      customObject.setValue();
      ...

    }
}
```

Then read above custom object from the second interceptor

```
@Intercepts(
        {
                @Signature(type = ResultSetHandler.class, method = "handleResultSets", args = {Statement.class})
        }
)
public class DecryptionResultInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
      ...
      customObject.getValue();
      ...
    }
}
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Assuming that your application uses thread-per-request model, check out [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).